# Developing Java EE in Eclipse; Entity Manager Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jpa, entitymanager

I am trying to create an Java Enterprise Application using Eclipse IDE with JBoss 7.0 Server. I already had experience developing such applications but using NetBeans IDE. The main problem for me are the differences between these two IDEs. Currently, Eclipse's giving me headaches about configuring basic functionalities.

The **project structure** looks like above. I've built Java EE application with 3 separated containers - one for EJB, JPA and WEB:

```
EAR:

-EJB -> contains SessionBeans and all the business logic

-JPA -> contains database entities (MySQL) and DAO layer

-WAR -> contains JSF (.xhtml) pages and JSF Managed Beans
```

I've configured those 3 containers to work together like Java EE environment and all works great. I can run my project on the server without any problems.

**Logic**

1. DAO layer is reading/inserting some data from JPA container; it manipulates the database entries
2. I am using the DAO layer's methods in EJB container; Stateless Session Beans are using those methods to sent the results to WAR container
3. JSF Managed beans in the WAR container receive the results from EJB Session Beans
4. Received results are then displayed on JSF page using JSF Managed Bean's object

**Problem**

I ran into a problem when I try to implement some basic functionality like reading from database. I am assuming that the problem I am facing with is the problem with **EntityManager**.

**Concrete problem**

I have my DAO layer that contains **UserDAOImpl** class that implements **IUserDAO** interface like down bellow.

IUserDAO interface:

```
public interface IUserDAO {
    public List<User> getAllUsers();
}
```

UserDAOImpl class:

```
public class UserDAOImpl implements IUserDAO {
//  @PersistenceContext(unitName="eLearningJJ-jpa") 
//  protected EntityManager entityManager;

    private EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("eLearningJJ-jpa");
    private EntityManager manager    = emf.createEntityManager(); 
    private List<User> users    = new ArrayList<User>();    

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        users = manager.createNamedQuery("User.findAll", User.class).getResultList();
        return users;
    }

}
```

This layer should be manipulating with the database entries or entities if you will.

User entity class

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name="USER_NAME")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="USER_PASSWORD")
    private String userPassword;

    public User() {
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserPassword() {
        return this.userPassword;
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }

}
```

Since I want to perform all the business logic in the EJB container, I have a **UserStateless Bean** that implements local interface **UserStatelessLocal** like down bellow:

UserStateless bean:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class UserStateless implements UserStatelessLocal {


    public UserStateless() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        IUserDAO userDao = new UserDAOImpl();
        return userDao.getAllUsers();
    }

}
```

UserStatelessLocal interface:

```
@Local
public interface UserStatelessLocal {
    public List<User> getAllUsers();
}
```

Now, the method **getAllUsers()** is called by the JSF Managed Bean in the Web container so I can list all users on the JSF page. This looks like down bellow:

LoginBean jsf managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean 
@SessionScoped 
public class LoginBean
{

    @EJB
    UserStatelessLocal userStatelessBean;
    ...
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userStatelessBean.getAllUsers();
    }

    ...
}
```

The method **getUsers()** is called on the **index.xhtml** page like down bellow:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{loginBean.users}" var="user" >
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{user.userName}" />
        </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

**To summarize**

The main problem for me is when I try to implement the *EntityManager* in **UserDAOImpl** class. Once I add those 2-3 lines of code I get **NullPointerException**. This is the stack trace:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:325)
root cause

javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:193)
    org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:261)
    org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:359)
    org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invoke(CMTTxInterceptor.java:219)
    org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:35)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.session.SessionInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SessionInvocationContextInterceptor.java:71)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:146)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:76)
    com.elearningjj.beans.UserStatelessLocal$$$view1.getAllUsers(Unknown Source)
    com.elearningjj.jsfbeans.LoginBean.getKorisnici(LoginBean.java:45)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:134)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:187)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:193)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:181)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:557)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1297)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:450)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:81)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:828)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:940)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1655)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:399)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.getStatus(JtaStatusHelper.java:72)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.isActive(JtaStatusHelper.java:114)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.join(CMTTransaction.java:149)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1197)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:170)
    org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:90)
    org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:111)
    org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:106)
    com.elearningjj.dao.UserDAOImpl.<init>(UserDAOImpl.java:25)
    com.elearningjj.beans.UserStateless.getAllUsers(UserStateless.java:28)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:51)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:45)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:44)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:202)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:44)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.session.SessionInvocationContextInterceptor$CustomSessionInvocationContext.proceed(SessionInvocationContextInterceptor.java:126)
    org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:257)
    org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:359)
    org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invoke(CMTTxInterceptor.java:219)
    org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:35)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.session.SessionInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SessionInvocationContextInterceptor.java:71)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:146)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
    org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:76)
    com.elearningjj.beans.UserStatelessLocal$$$view1.getAllUsers(Unknown Source)
    com.elearningjj.jsfbeans.LoginBean.getKorisnici(LoginBean.java:45)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:134)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:187)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:193)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:181)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:557)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1297)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:450)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:81)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:828)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:940)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1655)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:399)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.0.1.Final logs.
```

My persistance.xml in JPA container looks like this:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="eLearningJJ-jpa" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>

      <class>com.elearningjj.entities.User</class>
         <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
         </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I look forward to seeing your comments. If you need some extra details I am willing to show you ;-)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your EJB needs to be referenced by name I think :

`@EJB(mappedName="UserStatelessLocal/local")`

Another possibility is to get EJB by JNDI

It's probably a JBoss naming issue, not an Eclipse one

Comment: What about JBoss namings? And what about JBoss JNDI bindings and should I mess up with something with that?